# How to search for a substring, find the beginning and ending, and then check if that data is a weekday?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come up with the following which should be fairly close, but it's not quite right.  I am getting the following error when I try to test if the data is a weekday.  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'`

Here is my feeble code:

```
offset = str(link).find('Run:')
amount = offset + 15
pos = str(link)[offset:amount]
if pos.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    outF.write(str(link))
    outF.write('\n')
```

I'm looking for the string 'Run:  ' (it always has 2 blanks after the colon) and then I want to move 15 spaces to the right, to capture the date.  So, n-number of spaces to find 'Run:  ' and then get the date, like '2018-12-23' and test if this date is a weekday.  If this substring is a weekday, I want to write the entire string to a line in a CSV file (the writing to a CSV file works fine).  I'm just not sure how to find that one date (there are several dates in the string; I need the one immediately following 'Run:  ').

Comment: Please provide a sample input. What you are doing in the code does not make much sense given the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've only forgotten to [load it into a `datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

# ...
pos_date = datetime.strptime(pos, "%Y-%m-%d")
if pos_date.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):  
    # ...
```

---

Also, as you are using `.isoweekday()` and Monday is represented as 1, you don't really need to check the lower boundary:

```
if pos_date.isoweekday() <= 5:  # Monday..Friday
    # ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe to convert back to `datetime` type:

```
offset = str(link).find('Run:')
amount = offset + 15
pos = str(link)[offset:amount]
if datetime.strptime(pos,'%Y-%m-%d').isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    outF.write(str(link))
    outF.write('\n')
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Every single answer looks completely reasonable to me, but I keep getting this error.  SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.  Or, I get this error:  AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'.  Or, I get this: ValueError: time data 'Run: 2018-12-23' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'.
I am using this at the top: from datetime import datetime
It's almost like the date/time isn't working, and it can't understand the format of the date.  I understand you have to convert the string to a date, of course, but it just won't do the conversion.

Comment: Oh, now I see.  I had to drop the 'Run:', like this: pos = str(link)[offset+5:amount]
I thought Python could figure out that part, and just keep the part that looks like a date.  Also, there is 1 blank space after the colon not two.  Now it works.  Thanks everyone and Merry Christmas!!

Comment: @ryguy72 You too.. :-), didn't sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose your link is

```
link = "Your Link String is Run:  2018-12-21 21:15:48"
```

Your following code will work well to find the offset starting from `Run`

```
offset = str(link).find('Run:')
amount = offset + 16
```

Since, there are two spaces after `Run:` hence, 16 needs to be added to `offset`.
Now extracting exactly the date string `2018-12-21`, we need to add 6 to offset as `Run:`   has 6 character before starting the date string.

```
pos = str(link)[offset + 6:amount]
```

Now formatting our date string in an datetime object with

```
pos_date = datetime.strptime(pos, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

*Remember to import datetime at the top of your program file as*

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Now checking and displaying if the date is a weekday

```
if pos_date.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    print("It's a Week Day!")
```

This will return `It's a Week Day!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
link = "something something Run:  2018-12-24 ..."
offset = str(link).find('Run:') 
amount = offset +  15 # should be 16 
pos = str(link)[offset:amount] # this is a string
```

The `pos` of the example above will be `Run:  2018-12-24`, so it does not capture the date exactly.

A string object does not have `isoweekday` method, so `pos.isoweekday()` will result to error. But a `datetime.datetime` object does have that method.

A solution:

```
import datetime

link = "something something Run:  2018-12-24 ..."
offset = str(link).find('Run:') # will only give the index of 'R', so offset will be 20
amount = offset + 16
pos = str(link)[offset:amount] # pos is 'Run:  2018-12-24'
datestring = pos.split()[1] # split and capture only the date string

#now convert the string into datetime object
datelist = datestring.split('-')
date = datetime.datetime(int(datelist[0]), int(datelist[1]), int(datelist[2]))

if date.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    ....
```

This okay..?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to this would be to use dateutil.parser

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

try: 
    if parse(pos).isoweekday() <=5:
    ....
except ValueError:
    .....
```

The advantage here is that parse will accept a wide variety of date formats that datetime might error out for